# How can I better this code?

Tags: php, html, tags

I have this code :

```
<div class="boxContentScroll">
<?
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {                                                                                                                              
    ?>
        <div class="boxAddCategory<? if($row[1]==1) echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; ?>">
            <div class="boxAddCategory1">
                <? echo $row[0]."<br />"; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="boxAddCategory2">                               
                <? 
                    if((isset($_SESSION['admin'])) && ($_SESSION['admin']==1)) {
                    ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" <? if($row[1]==1) echo "checked='checked'" ?> value="categories[]" />
                    <?
                    } else echo "&nbsp;" 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?
    }
?>
</div>
```

but is not so good read it (just watch the number of `?>` or `<?`). What can you suggest to improve it? Thanks

Comment: You could separate database calls and template =)

Comment: You could start by using `<?php` instead of `<?` ^_^

Comment: You could use colons like `<?php if ($cond): ?>Output<?php endif; ?>` O.o

Comment: @Shaz: this would be relevant only if the code was going to be put up for public use. On a site/server under your control, short tags are not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want this code to run on all environments, don't use short_tags (`<?`). But if you're running this on your own server, you can disregard it.
2. Use PHP's [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for control structures. This will make it much more readable.
3. Don't mix your business logic with your view logic. Either setup your own MVC stack or use a templating engine if you want.

Comment: I like `{` and `}` because editors know where if/else blocks start and end. Also I wouldn't call 1 db action business logic =)

Comment: Never mind that PHP *IS* a templating engine. Amazing how many people treat PHP like inception and want to add yet another layer on top of things.

Comment: `endif; endforeach;` is more understandable than `}}` IMHO

Comment: @rudie, yeah it's funny. Eclipse throws and error if they aren't paired, but never highlights the pairs when you don't use `{}`. It _starts_ at 1 sql call and before you know it everything is dumped on the view. We must be disciplined! *snaps whip!*

Comment: @MarcB haha, I was waiting for that obligatory comment. I usually add a disclaimer but it's pretty late here. And I agree, you don't _really_ need it.

Comment: Rudie - Whether it's one or a hundred, it's still business logic and should be put into a separate file, or at the very least is better put in a separate section of the file, as opposed to inline.

Comment: "If you want this code to run on any server, don't use short_tags (`<?`). But if you're running this on your own server, you can disregard it" Contradiction! (I see what you are going for, but perhaps make it more clear?)

Comment: @JohnP I don't use Eclipse =) Too much crap. I use Notepad++. Perfect. Only with `{` and `}` does it show how things relate. With alt syntax you must have perfect indentation (and sometimes you make a mistake and you're looking for 20 minutes where that `endif` started)

Comment: @Shauna I agree. That's why I said: "You could separate database calls and template =)"

Comment: I see hard programming by using MVC on PHP... just this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I would start with replacing if with short version:

`<?php echo ($row[1]==1) ? "Yes" : "No"; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You could write this:

```
<? if($row[1]==1) echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; ?>
```

like this:

```
<?= $row[1] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No' ?>
```

And you could replace this:

```
if((isset($_SESSION['admin'])) && ($_SESSION['admin']==1)) {
```

with this:

```
if ( $admin ) {
```

and put this before the while loop:

```
$admin = isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're in a loop and have a static condition to check like this:

```
if((isset($_SESSION['admin'])) && ($_SESSION['admin']==1))
```

Define it in a variable it outside the loop. If it won't change within the loop, you don't have to check each time, only once. This becomes relevant when doing resource intensive checks and function calls that won't produce a different result outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="boxContentScroll">
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) : ?>                                                                                                                             
        <div class="boxAddCategory <?=($row[1] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No')?>">
            <div class="boxAddCategory1">
                <?=$row[0].'<br />'?>
            </div>

            <div class="boxAddCategory2">                               
                <?php if((isset($_SESSION['admin'])) && ($_SESSION['admin']==1)) : ?>
                <input type="checkbox" <?=($row[1]==1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?> value="categories[]" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a HEREDOC:

```
<div class="boxContentScroll">
<?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $class = ($row[1]==1) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
        $checked = ($class) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $data = $row[0];
        $admin = (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin']==1) ? 1 : 0;

        echo <<< HTML
    <div class="boxAddCategory{$class}">
        <div class="boxAddCategory1">
            {$data}
        </div>
HTML;
        if ($admin) {
            echo <<< HTML
        <div class="boxAddCategory2">
            <input type="checkbox" value="categories[]" {$checked} />
        </div>
HTML;
        }
        echo <<< HTML
    </div>
HTML;
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is even harder to read than the original code. Do you really use HEREDOC like this in your projects?

Comment: @Wesley: Like this? Not if it can be avoided.

Comment: I think it can probably always be avoided.

Comment: @Wesley: HEREDOC is messy, I don't think there's any way around that. It has its uses, though.